# Wordpress website with extreme PHP usage

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, cpanel, fastcgi

Last week we transferred a website from another hosting company to our server. The website (wordpress) is quite popular and can easily reach 1100 people viewing at peak moments. We decided to go with a 12 vCPU server with 32GB RAM and SSD storage, running on Linux CentOS 6 and cPanel/WHM as backend. We have PHP 5.6 installed with Fast-CGI.

The problem is, server-side is the server very slow and I can't find a fix anywhere. I have browsed through a lot of websites and looked at everyone of them. I found W3 Total Cache which works perfectly but the CPU usage problem still exists.

I've tried deactivating and activating plugins but that also wouldn't do the trick. The theme is custom build and wasn't coded that good but there were no major problems that can cause that CPU to rise to 100% when only 2 users visit the website.

Then rebuild Apache with Zend opcache and installed nginx. Still no luck, and this wouldn't solve the problem, it would only make it less worse like W3 Total Cache.

Currently I'm not even sure where the problem is, it could be Wordpress, cPanel or Linux and I actually think there is some weird setting in PHP or something where I don't know about. Anyways, I have no idea anymore.

Some extra info:

```
I/O wait is at 0%, always.
Memory stays steady at 8 - 9% of 32GB
Disk Usage around 1%
Processes stay steady between 90 and 120
```

PHP Info file: https://jsfiddle.net/qyLgb0t8/1/

CPU Usage with 2 visitors:

```
php - 67,2%
mysqld - 2,3%
httpd - 0%
python - 0%
Everything else also 0%
```

It would be great to hear from someone who had similar issues in the past. Generally I need to solve this problem. I'm clueless at this point.

Comment: Are you using php-fpm? Are you using a caching layer such as Varnish? These will greatly help.

Comment: Also, make sure xdebug and xhprof is disabled in your php config, those debugging tools can greatly slow down PHP performance.

Comment: wordpress has always been a dog.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I'm using Fast-CGI because this was prefixed in cPanel. I'll look into Varnish, saw another post with that but does it solve the PHP problem?

Comment: Check your Apache logs. There are lots of brute-force attackers out there who try to hit /xmlrpc.php in particular. This can cause a huge load from a single IP address because it requires a PHP process (it can't be cached by W3 Total Cache). If you don't need xmlrpc, disable it entirely. If you do, see if you can identify an attacker or two and block them at the firewall level.

Answer (score 1):

you can try varmish cache

or just change your webserver to litespeed, i think it might be easier for you to use litespeed as litespeed can be install and easily integrated with your existing cpanel server

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you please try with the nginx webserver. You can install free nginxcp plugin on your cPanel server and will get GUI panel to manage nginx configuration in your WHM.

Answer (score 0):

Litespeed has a caching plugin for Wordpress and will make a huge difference on your server. Well worth the investment, try their 15-day trial. https://www.litespeedtech.com/products/litespeed-web-server/download/get-a-trial-license